# Movable DialogFragment in Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-dialogfragment

Can we make a DialogFragment movable with drag & drop functionality ? I know we can use PopupWindow but I need to reuse the DialogFragment we already implemented for another purpose...

--
Thanks in Advance,
heyjii